# Multiple Screen Android

Tags: android, screen

how to create multiple screens for all android devices, which one is the most effective ?

Currently I use the manual method.

1.[JAVA] I set config screen layouts and get its density, then I set the screen size of its corresponding

Example:

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int density = metrics.densityDpi;
    if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {

    }
}
```

2.[XML] create folder layout, ex:

```
layout-large-mdpi
layout-normal-ldpi
layout-large-tvdpi
```

I think the way 1 and 2 above is less effective and require a long time to make this.

is there a simple way for multiple screens for all android devices with effective? Thanks

Comment: Create separate layout as in "2".Try to create Xml which can adapt to multiple screens.

Comment: yes I've done this before, but I think the same if I have a project that requires a lot of layouts and i set width and height per layouts.
is there other suggestions?

Comment: Via code as in option 1 is cool and much faster than using an Xml but you might not get the flexibility  and your code might get more complex

Comment: Hardcoding stuff isn't cool and I doubt it's much faster. You should prefer XML. Use dip (density independent pixels) for view width and height instead of pixels and the views will look good on any screen.

Comment: yes I think one effective way than the way 2, but the same requires a long time to make this
is there a quick tool for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a style to your widget or you can set a theme which applies to all widgets.
It's not very complicated and saves a lot of time.

Go to your values directory and open the styles.xml...

Put in this...

```
<style name="Style.Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
</style>
```

This defines a new button style, the button will be 48x48dp and the text color will be red.

You can set this style to any of your buttons with

```
<Button 
    style="@style/Style.Button"/>
```

To set this to apply to all buttons, create a theme like this...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Style.Button</item>
</style>
```

and set it in your manifest ...

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Now all buttons will look the same. You can do this with any widget, and you can have several styles.xml, e.g. one in values and one in values-xlarge ...

Comment: it's same with way "2"... i set size per style in different values

Comment: No it's not. You have to create a THEME, not just a style.

Answer (score -1):

You could create more layout folder like layout-sw720dp and put your specific layout in.

Then you could add drawable folder like drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi and put your XML drawables in.

Maybe my blog could clear things up. http://objectofclasshuman.blogspot.de/2014/04/android-user-interface.html

Comment: Please refrain from posting answers that are just links.

Comment: I know it isn't the desired way of sharing information but in my opinion this topic is to big to fit in here. I will try to make it better next time.

Comment: Thx for downvoting. ;-)